# Почему new Image не показывает изображения и выдает Image is not defined?

Tags: javascript, dom

Пытаюсь добавить изображения на сайт с помощью new Image, но ничего не выходит. Хотя если вместо ссылки на изображение на сайте указать ссылку на локальное изображение, то оно появления, но консоль всё равно выдает Image is not defined.

Ниже код JS:

```
const cosm1 = "Аддала.jpeg";

const cosm2 = "https://cdn.eso.org/images/screen/eso1124d.jpg";

const cosm3 = "https://cosmos.network/og-image.jpg";

    const img = new Image();
    img.width = 500;
    img.height = 560;
    img.src = cosm1;

    const img2 = new Image();
    img2.width = 500;
    img2.height = 500;
    img2.src = cosm2;
   
    const img3 = new Image();
    img3.src = cosm3;
    img32.width = 500;
    img3.width = 300;
   
    document.body.append(img);
    document.body.append(img2);
    document.body.append(img3);
```

Первое изображение появляется, остальные нет. Но если указать в самом HTML через тег img, то остальные тоже появляются.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/280049/6104996   ///////////  просто картинка ещё не загрузилась

Comment: Делайте добавление в body внутри img.onload(...)